# Почему добавленный элемент "NULL" , а не count($a)?

Tags: php, массивы

Функция должна принять один аргумент в виде массива и дописать в него последним элементом количество значений массива.

```
function maspush (array $a) {

    array_push($a,$a[count($a)]);

    var_dump($a);
}

$a = array(2,4,5,'f',3,'u',899,'c','k');

maspush($a);
```

Comment: у Vesper ответ лучше. он с обьяснением. в математике результат без обьясления не засчитывается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь добавить в массив не сам `count($a)`, а элемент массива по этому индексу. А так как массивы в PHP индексируются с нуля, элемент по индексу `count($a)` всегда будет отсутствовать, т.е. будет NULL. Нужно класть в массив само значение `count($a)`.

```
array_push($a, count($a));
```

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так

```
function maspush (array $a) {
    array_push($a, count($a));
    var_dump($a);
}

$a = array(2, 4, 5, 'f', 3, 'u', 899, 'c', 'k');
maspush($a);
```

Comment: Хотя и правильно, но лучше объяснить, что за ошибка была в коде, и как именно она была исправлена. Даже если она настолько тривиальна, как `if (a=0)` в коде на Си.

Comment: я из тех кому легче сделать - чем объяснить